# Can I use facebook_scraper on colab?

Tags: python

I use facebook_scraper on colab like this code

```
%pip install facebook-scraper
from facebook_scraper import get_group_info
get_group_info("Arduino")
```

It show error like this.

```
LoginRequired                             Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-4-f5fabc9f58d7> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 from facebook_scraper import get_group_info
----> 2 get_group_info("Arduino")

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/facebook_scraper/facebook_scraper.py in get(self, url, **kwargs)
    940                     or response.url.startswith(utils.urljoin(FB_W3_BASE_URL, "login"))
    941                 ):
--> 942                     raise exceptions.LoginRequired(
    943                         "A login (cookies) is required to see this page"
    944                     )

LoginRequired: A login (cookies) is required to see this page
```

I don't how to set cookie in colab. How to fix it?